# jquery changing multiple classes to affect z-index and other properties

Tags: jquery, class, addclass, removeclass

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.  I have a feature I'm developing that is going to be using several different characteristics and only have the beginnings of it at this stage.

My goal is to have 4 different boxes stacked over each other, somewhat like a tab.  I have it so that I can select one of the boxes and it comes to the front, but I'd like to be able to change the classes of the 3 remaining boxes accordingly so they stack neatly.

**JavaScript**:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sites div').click(function () {
            $('.topZ-index').removeClass('topZ-index');
            $(this).addClass('topZ-index');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="sites">
    <div id="layer1" class="layer1"></div>
    <div id="layer2" class="layer2"></div>
    <div id="layer3" class="layer3"></div>
    <div id="layer4" class="layer4"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I have so far, with each div having a margin-top and margin-left off centered from the one it overlaps.

I see many examples of toggling between two items, but this involves 4 different layers

I know that I'll want to eventually use the easing and timer files as well as some other ones to slide the selected box smoothly to the front, and add a slight fading to non selected items.  I'm not sure how much bearing that has at this beginning stage though.

At this point, I just need the boxes to stack correctly.

I'm aiming to visually get an effect similar to that of pulling a card out of a deck and placing it on top.  It appears, that I might need to change the id as well, but I'm not sure how possible that is in jquery.

In any case using firebug, this is an example of what the html would need to look like after I selected a box.

```
<div id="sites">
    <div id="layer1" class="layer1"></div>
    <div id="layer4" class="layer2 topZ-index"></div>
    <div id="layer2" class="layer3"></div>
    <div id="layer3" class="layer4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you started working on the CSS yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you have classes zindex1 through zindex4, which implement the stacking order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sites div').click(function() {
        $('#sites div').removeClass('zindex1 zindex2 zindex3 zindex4');
        $(this).addClass('zindex1');
        var index = 2;
        var top = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#sites div').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('id') != top) {
                $(this).addClass("zindex" + index);
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

See my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/HJAUp/)

Comment: I tried this, but it only seemed to work the once.  I'm basically aiming for something that looks like pulling a playing card out of a deck and placing it on the top of the pile.  I've realized that to change the class alone does not really get the effect I need, but I know from the past that changing ids with jquery either can get a little fuzzy or is near impossible.

Comment: See my edit. The problem with the previous version is that `$(this) != top` doesn't work -- two jQuery objects referring to the same DOM element are not necessarily equal. I changed it to compare IDs. If just changing classes isn't enough, maybe you can do more things in the loop to do what you want.

Comment: This works really well!  Is there a way to pass the value into the layer1 through 4 classes to match up with where the zindex classes are going?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by manipulating z-index. For example:

```
 $('#sites div').click(function () {

     var max_zindex = 0;

     $('.layer').each(function() {
            var zindex =  parseInt($(this).css("z-index"), 10);
         if(zindex > max_zindex) 
            max_zindex = zindex;                     
     });
     max_zindex++; 
    $(this).css('z-index', max_zindex);
  });
```

Check here working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/h3WaL/2/
​

Comment: I believe that I'm going to have to actually change the entire class rather than just the z-index.  I took a look at the demo and it basically what the code I have does.